# Find the probability that there is a vowel in x is approximately

Tags: probability

Let S be the set of all strings of length 3 over the alphabet {a,b,c}. If you choose randomly an element x of S, the probability that there is a vowel in x is approximately.

A. 1/3

B. 1/2

C. 2/3

D. 1

My answer is A, but I got it wrong. The correct one is C, and I don't know why?

Thank You

Comment: list the 27 elements of $S$ ... how many contain the letter $a$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider drawing with replacement,

\begin{align}
Pr(a \text{ appears in } x) &= 1 - Pr(a \text{ does not appear in }x) \\
&=1 - \left( \frac23\right)^3\\
&= 1-\frac8{27} \\
&= \frac{19}{27} \approx \frac{18}{27}=\frac23
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Each of the three letters in $x$ is selected independently (with replacement) from an alphabet of $3$ options, one of which is a vowel and two of which are consonants.   That is a total of $3^3$ equally probable outcomes, with $2^3$ of them containing only consonants, and (*how many*) do not.

The probability that there is at least one vowel in $x$ is: $\dfrac{?}{3^3}$

Answer (score 0):

Donald Splutterwit  has given a good hint in his comment that will lead you to the answer. Let me attempt to tell you why your answer (1/3) is wrong.

Your answer is correct for a single letter. Assume you have heavy coin which has probabilty 1/3 of coming with head when tossed. (That is a single toss) But when you toss is three times the probability of getting head at least once should increase. Same way a vowel (it is the letter *a* here) has probability of 1/3 when selected from $\{a,b,c\}$. But in a string a 3 letters the chances of *a* being present should shoot up. Theactual numerical calculations are given by others. I hope this intuitive explanation helps you understand.